# R package development with GitHub

Tags: r, github

I just created my first R package and started my first GitHub repo. The main function of the R package and some data files are still in development and I would like to track changes with colleagues on GitHub.

Should my repo consist of prepackaged files (pre-Rd) or packaged files? Every other R repo I've seen has packaged files but I assume they aren't still in the initial development phase.

Comment: Read R Packages by H Wickham for details, the go is to commit Rd files generated by roxygen2 then it is directly installable from R

Comment: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/ as someone put it on reserve at our library all semester. Good info and more than can be fully understood in 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build a package then you should start building it with the appropriate directories and supplemental files, but you just work on developing your source code until you've created a minimum viable product, at which one you can create an install-able package and update it as often as you like.

Truly, the sooner that you create the package the better because it paves the way to the best practice of iterative development and it also helps you to spot bugs as you make changes to your source code.

There's a good tutorial on building packages on GitHub at this blog I like called [Hack-R.com](http://hack-r.com) (shameless self-promotion).

http://hack-r.com/write-an-r-package-from-scratch-with-github/